# _bios_keybrd function in Linux

Tags: linux

How can I use the [`_bios_keybrd`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_65.html) function in Linux since `bios.h` is not included in Linux? I would like to convert my DOS code to Linux.

Comment: I don't think Linux kernel will allow int not-0x80 in userspace, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent; you can’t access the low-level keyboard functions in the same way under Linux as you can under DOS.

If your DOS code implements a game, I recommend looking at [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) or [Allegro](https://liballeg.org/) (which is also available on DOS); both of these provide keyboard access which appears similar to low-level DOS/BIOS access from the programmer’s perspective, while fitting within the Linux constraints.

If your DOS code implements a command-line tool, you should read from standard input instead of directly from the keyboard.

If your DOS code implements a text-based interface, you could look at [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

All of these will require more porting effort than a straightforward one-to-one mapping of functions. You might want to look at [Planet Blupi](http://blupi.org/) which was recently ported from DOS to Linux, using SDL.